# where to place my htmls files in spring mvc

Tags: spring

I have a jsp page where I have used a hyperlink to hover to a html page. Where I need to place the html file in my spring mvc project.

### login.jsp

```
    <table>     
    <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><center><input type="submit" value="Login" /></center></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <table>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><center><a href="register.html">Click here to register</a></center></td></tr>
    </table>
    </center>
```

location of login.jsp in my project is 
/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp

Where should I place the "register.html" in my spring MVC project?
Because when I am placing the html file under webContent then it's throwing "page not found".

Comment: The location of the JSP is irrelevant. Relative paths are resolved against the path of the current URL, i.e. the path to which the controller displaying this view is mapped, that you see in the browser address bar. I would simply use absolute paths, which would make your code more robust: `<a href="<c:url value='/register.html'/>">`

Comment: is this a spring boot project or a normal spring project ?

Comment: This is a simple spring project.

Comment: login.jsp page is working fine. But while clicking on the hyperlink, the page is getting error out saying page not found.

Answer (score 0):

This was already mentioned in the comments, but it seems like your problem is that you point to the relative path for register.html. Since you put it directly in WebContent that's two levels up. So in your url you want it to say ../../register.html
However, it is better to use the absolute path, so you can use just /register.html.

If you find that neither approach works, try moving the register.html to the same place as the file containing your link and leaving it as-is in your code (just register.html) and see if you can access the page from there.

Comment: I tried with both the options
1.<a href="<c:url value='/register.html'/>">
2.../../register.html
but i am getting the below error
HTTP Status 404 - /register.html

type Status report

message /register.html

description The requested resource is not available
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Though i have the register.html placed in webContent folder.